# Creating a new database using NPoco

Tags: npoco

I'm trying to create a database using NPoco. I would like to know how I could do that ? Please list out the ways to create/initiate Database in Npoco .Thanks in Advance

Comment: Take look at [Fluent Migrator](https://github.com/schambers/fluentmigrator) We use it for all database migrations and versioning.

Answer (score 0):

You don't. Npoco is not responsible for creating the database and scheme etc. It's a micro orm for querying and mapping.

You need to script off your database yourself.

Comment: Thanks. That means I have to manually create tables in the database and write scripts for that ?